Using the r-Lambert function to solve a system of transcendental equations
I am trying to use the r-Lambert function applied to a vector in order to solve a system of transcendental equations, however, I am facing some difficulties when trying to obtain the right expression to use a result I found on a paper.
I have :
$$
-V(V^{-1}v + q + V^{-1}A) \oslash V(V^{-1}v+q+V^{-1}Z) \odot \exp((A-Z)\odot q) = \exp(y-b)
$$
Where I wanted to cancel the V's but I can't do it. $A$, $Z$ $y, b, v, q$ are vectors and $V$ is a positive definite, symmetric invertible matrix. $exp$ denotes the element-wise exponential of a vector.
I am trying to find an expression of the type :
$$
\frac{q-t}{q-s}e^{cq} =  a
$$
Where I expect to use the theorem 3 of this paper : https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2017-369-11/S0002-9947-2017-06911-7/S0002-9947-2017-06911-7.pdf
The Hadamard product is new to me, any help regarding this problem is very much appreciated !
